# Setting Variable in JavaScript Not Working

Tags: javascript, authentication

I have made this little JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(perm == 0)
{
var perm = 0;
var password = "showrocks69";
var pass = prompt("[Login] Type in the Admin CP Password:","");
if(pass==password)
{
perm = 1;
window.location = "http://cod5showtime.url.ph/acp.html";
}
else
{
alert("[Error] Invalid Password!");
window.location = "http://cod5showtime.url.ph/";
}
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function acpLogout()
{
var perm = 0;
alert("[Log Out] Logged out from Administrator Account");
window.location = "http://cod5showtime.url.ph/";
}
</script>
```

And this button:

```
<button class="btn" onClick="acpLogout()">Log Out</button>
```

I want to make it when someone clicks Log out the person will get logged out aka the 'perm' variable will be set to 0. I've tried to accomplish this as seen above and it's not working. Any Ideas ?

Comment: it's working fine..try alerting variable perm: alert(perm); inside function acpLogout()

Comment: Okay, I've added the alert(perm); and it shows 0, so it means the variable gets set, but then why it won't ask me to type in the password again when I visit the page ?

Comment: you are relocating the window after this..so its not executing other part..

Comment: I've removed the window.location and it still doesn't work.

Comment: If I'd do that it would destroy the purpose of the script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit the page again, a whole new JavaScript context is created, with a new 'perm' variable which is initially undefined and then follows your code. There is no way to have a variable survive page reloads.

What you can do however is save the information you want (whether the user is logged or not) in a more permanent medium (like cookies or some HTML5 storage):

```
// first thing you do get the variable from localStorage
var perm = localStorage.getItem('loggedState');

if (perm === 'loggedOut') {
  // code for logged out
} else {
  // code for logged in
}

function logout() {
  perm = 'loggedOut';
  // save the variable to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('loggedState', perm);
}

function login() {
  perm = 'loggedIn';
  // save the variable to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('loggedState', perm);
}
```

Note that by no means do i consider this approach to be ok for handling roles/permissions, but it does solve OP's immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function acpLogout()
            {
            var perm = 0;
            alert(perm);
            alert("[Log Out] Logged out from Administrator Account");



            if(perm == 0)
            {
            var perm = 0;
            var password = "showrocks69";
            alert(password);
            var pass = prompt("[Login] Type in the Admin CP Password:","");
            if(pass==password)
            {
            perm = 1;
            window.location = "http://cod5showtime.url.ph/acp.html";
            }
            else
            {
            alert("[Error] Invalid Password!");
            window.location = "http://cod5showtime.url.ph/";
            }
            }
            }
            </script>
            <br />


            <button class="btn" onClick="acpLogout()">Log Out</button>
```

Comment: It workes, like, the dialog that asks for the password appears after I click on the button, but if I refresh the page the problem would return.